# Why does npm not work in VSCode terminal on Linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm

In VSCode I can't use npm command

In linux console

```
zosia@zosia-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC:~$ which npm
/home/zosia/.nvm/versions/node/v4.9.1/bin/npm

zosia@zosia-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC:~$ whereis node
node: /usr/bin/node /usr/include/node /home/zosia/.nvm/versions/node/v4.9.1/bin/node /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz
```

In VSC terminal:

```
sh-5.1$ which npm
which: no npm in (/app/bin:/app/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin:/home/zosia/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/node_modules/bin)
sudo: npm: command not found

sh-5.1$ whereis node
[296 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Warning: waitpid override ignores groups
node:
[296 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Warning: waitpid override ignores groups
```

I expecting to works npm in VSC

Comment: `/home/zosia/.nvm/versions/node/v4.9.1/bin` is not in your shell's path when running from Code terminal. You don't even get the same prompt, they can even be different shells.

Comment: Yes. I use command: source ~/.bashrc in VSCode and it's work